# position of decimal point is determined by the program

Tags: javascript, php, html

The software that we use for the register at my place of work puts automatically the decimal point as I enter the money quantity and if the quantity is an integer then I need to put 2 zeros so the decimal point is in the correct place.

I'm trying to implement that same feature in my program but the only answers I'm seeing is to use the step property in html.  Probably I need to use javascript but I'm not sure how to tackle this problems.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

### [Number.prototype.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

This is supported by all the browsers.